# How to get coordinates for a bounding box

Tags: java, geolocation, latitude-longitude, yelp

I am trying to use the Yelp API's bounding box method: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api#searchGBB

I want the bounding box to be the entire US. and I used the following coordinates for it:

```
request.addQuerystringParameter("bounds", "38.266224,-122.541803"+"|"+"44.018501,-72.092587");
```

However, the API isn't finding business across the US. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be choosing other coordinates?

Comment: looks ok to me, thus would first check how the Url used in the query ends up looking like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.The coordinates you have chosen is too large.You should choose other coordinates.
In your code you have chosen northeast longitude vale as -72.092587 replace by -122.092587.

Your code should be:

```
request.addQuerystringParameter("bounds", "38.266224,-122.541803"+"|"+"44.018501,-122.092587);
```